# Find location by means other than GPS / phone network in Android?

Tags: android, geolocation

I'm working on an android app that needs to constantly get location data, or as constantly as possible. I know this is going to drain the battery and use lots of data if the user isn't on wifi.

Is there any other way to transmit some kind of you are here message to a phone that wouldn't use data or be a constant drain on the battery by using the GPS. I know enough about phones to think this is a stupid question but I also know enough to know I don't know that much.

So does anyone extremely familiar with Android know *if there is any way to get location data, or any data, to the phone without using the GPS or your data connection?*

Background:
I'm working on an app that notifies the user about interesting things when they are within some radius of a location, like a historical site or mall or theater, I don't really want to constantly ask the GPS or phone network where they are but I don't know of any other way.

Comment: You asked two general questions; I've focused on one based on the accepted answer. (I don't think it was a bad question, but it was muddled; focus future questions better.)

Comment: It *might* be possible to get an estimate of movement using the accelerometer, and update using the GPS every few minutes, but I doubt that would be easy (or accurate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get Location Strategies for Android:**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: Seems like that has my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way.  You must use  GPS or data.